# Best free file manager for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, file-manager

i am looking for a free file manager for my project in ASP.Net, so can any show me?

**Edit:**
A file manager or a image manager for user to use to upload/select/create folder/delete files...

Comment: To manage your project of a file manager to use within your project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am also looking for a (free) ASP.Net based file manager and just did a brief survey.  I tried Bipin Joshi's "Web Site File Manager" (the binaryintellect one referenced by DKarter).  While it works, I felt it is going to be difficult to customize, it is a web page while I really need a control, and it is a bit dated at this point.

I almost gave up hope when I stumbled on IZWebFileManager:
<s>http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/demo/default.aspx</s>
Moved here: https://github.com/manishma/IZWebFileManager

It is licensed under the GNU GPL and it took 5 minutes to get running.  I downloaded the code, added the DLLs to my project, and then added the control to a page, and bam - I had a professional looking fully functional web based file manager.

```
<iz:FileManager ID="FileManager1" runat="server" Height="400" Width="600">
    <RootDirectories>
        <iz:RootDirectory DirectoryPath="~/Content" Text="Content Folder" />
    </RootDirectories>
</iz:FileManager>
```

Comment: I want this, how to use it after downloaded? I dont see any DLLs library or a "how to use" file or something like that?

Comment: Available here : https://github.com/manishma/IZWebFileManager

Comment: The latest changes were made about 5 years ago, Although I'll check it but do you still using it?

Answer (score 4):

Try these:

http://www.filemanager.3ntar.net

and

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/44b73e89-78d9-4ad7-8157-bce54ad31fde.aspx

They are not that good but it's pretty straight forward to build one yourself. Just make a recursive function and populate a tree control.
I actually might have some code I wrote for one of the companies I worked for. Let me know if you are interested and I'll try to post it here somehow.

Comment: It looks like http://www.filemanager.3ntar.net is no longer online

Comment: http://filemanager.3ntar.net is online