# Display folders and files from a remote desktop computer on a website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to make a website which is able to display all the folders and files which is placed on a remote computer, and here afterwards but is there a good way to do this?
I've been looking on RDP and RDC and here you have to use a remote desktop application in order du do this.
i'm working with asp.net, C# and javaScript

But is there a way to display the folder system on a website
like :

C: drive (freesspace)
 (then comes all the folders on c drive)
 folder 1
  (and in each folder comes all the files)
  file 1
  file 2
  file 3
 folder 2
 folder 3

i've been looking alittle on ConnectionOptions and it looks like it would do the trick, but does it work?  and/or is there another way.
found this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27ea1e6d-dc11-4ed0-a3d8-1d1462231848/remotely-access-the-computer-c but not sure if it would work.

Need your help!
Regards Kasper

Comment: I'd recommend making a small WCF service on the target machine (The one whose files are being read) to simplify development a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a file manager, see this question:
[Best free file manager for ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824473/best-free-file-manager-for-asp-net/7302951#7302951)

The best option is this guy:
http://www.izwebfilemanager.com/

With that said, it is a little dubious of a security proposition to expose the entire hard drive of a remote machine in a web app.